# What is there in the book Cohomologie non abélienne by Jean Giraud

Tags: stacks, gerbes

These days I am trying to understand about stacks and gerbes.

Most of the articles that has something to do with gerbes cite this work Cohomologie non abélienne by Jean Giraud.

I do not read the language it is written in and I could not see an English translation for the same.

It would definitely give some motivation to know what is there in this master’s work. I am not asking to summarise 400 pages work in an answer. Some information about outline of a particular topic would be useful(I am not sure if it is even possible).

Comment: Giraud develops a theory of nonabelian cohomology in a very general setting. His $H^2$ classifies the gerbes bound by a given band (lien). It is written in the style of EGA, which many of us find unattractive. There is a 4 page summary in the appendix to Tannakian Categories by Deligne and Milne. http://www.jmilne.org/math/xnotes/tc.html

Comment: If you have  access to MathSciNet, look up the work (searching e. g. by author or title). The review looks like a good place to start; the number is  MR0344253.

Comment: @MargaretFriedland that is a good choice I believe. Right now I am in my home(where I don’t have access to Math sci net), I go to institute on Monday. I will see that then. Thanks.

Comment: @anon thanks for comment. I have seen that just now. It’s obly definitions they mention.